# Efficient way to unnest pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm accessing a fairly large series of json files and storing them in a pandas series, part of a larger dataframe. There are several fields I want in said json, some of which are nested. I've been extracting them using json_normalize. The goal in to then merge these new fields with my original dataframe.

My problem is when I do so, instead of getting a dataframe with J rows and K columns, I get a J length series with each element being 1xK dataframe.  I'm wondering if there is either an efficient vectorized way to turn this nested series/dataframe into a regular dataframe or get a regular dataframe from the start.

I've used map/lambda to create my nested series.  Right now I'm unnesting with iteritems/append, but there has to be a more efficient way.

```
url_base = 'http:\\foo.bar='
df['http'] = df['id'].map(lambda x: url_base + x)
df['json'] = df['http'].map(lambda x: nf.get_json(x))
nest_ser = df['json'].map(lambda x: json_normalize(x))
df = pd.DataFrame()
for index, item in nest_ser.iteritems():
   df = df.append(item)
```

json_normalize produces:

```
pd.Series([pd.DataFrame([col1,col2...]),[pd.DataFrame([col1,col2...]),[pd.DataFrame([col1,col2...]))
```

instead of

```
pd.DataFrame([col1,col2...])
```

Comment: Can you share the actual url/some test data so that people can run your code? See: [mcve]. Also, unless I’m misundertnding

Comment: * what you’re trying to do, a DataFrame may not be the best data structure to use.

Comment: This is for work and I'm afraid I can't really go into concrete examples.  :(  I'm a support engineer and not really a dev.  Picked up some python in school and I've found it can make automating things a lot easier.

Comment: Could you share some test data in the same format but with random/example contents? Hell, if you share just the format of the DataFrame I can generate some data myself, it doesn't really matter. The more important part would be the missing code (`nf.get_json()`, `json_normalize`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

suppose your name of the output series out of json_normalize is sr:

```
pd.concat(sr.tolist())
```